# How to call async/await function asynchronously in other functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I create common function that will be called several different times and that function is async/await type.

```
const storeData = async () => {
   await User.create({name: "Test 123"})
}
```

Now if I want to call function storeData in many different functions asynchronously, do I call it with await in a front of it (option 1 bellow) or since it has async await inside of it, will be run as async function and there is no need for await in front (option 2 bellow)?

(Note: I could do workaround and make storeData to return a new Promise and then do the things inside the promise and be sure that **await** will really matters.)

Option 1.

```
async dummy1() {

   await storeData();

   ...rest of thte code

}
```

Option 2.

```
async dummy2() {

   storeData();

   ...rest of the code

}
```

Comment: "*I could do workaround and make storeData to return a new Promise*" - `storeData` already **does** return a promise, because you made it an `async` function. And that means you need to place an `await` in front of the call if you want the `...rest of the code` to run after that promise fulfills.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, all asynchronous functions are identical to a regular function that returns a promise. The `async` is just syntactic sugar. So, if you use `await` before the function call, the function call will block execution, and if you don't use `await` then it'll run asynchronously, like you desire.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: in the link you provided, in his first code snippet, on line 16, he is calling function asyncCall(); How can he make sure that function asyncCall(); is run asynchronously? I am familiar how Promises and Async/Await works, but what I can not find is this specific question. Maybe you did not understand my question well

Comment: Asynchronous functions always run asynchronously, the `await` is just syntactic sugar for a promise.

Comment: so what you are saying is that it actually doesn't matter whether I put await or not in front of it, it will run as async because inside of it, it is actually async?

Comment: If you run `await storeData()` in `dummy1`, `storeData` will run the same as if you didn't put `await` in front, but `dummy1` will wait for `storeData` to finish before continuing.